# SignInManager.SignIn with non-existing user

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity, owin

I just created a ASP.MVC project and want to provide temporary login (let's call it guest login). This should not require a registration and I want to avoid the creation of a database entry for this user.

I extended the default Login-action of the AccountController by:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return View(model);

    if (model.GuestLogin) {
        var user = UserManager.FindByEmail(model.Email);
        if (user != null) {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
            return View(model);
        }

        var appUser = new ApplicationUser() { Email = model.Email, UserName = model.Email, Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() };
        //var creationResult = UserManager.Create(appUser);
        SignInManager.SignIn(appUser, false, model.RememberMe);
        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
    }

    //common login stuff ...
}
```

The SignIn-call fails with:
**System.InvalidOperationException: UserId not found.**

Is it possible to archive this somehow, or not?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay,

the devil lies in the ClaimsIdentityFactory, which tries to add some user entity related claims (e.g. user role or security stamp claims) during sign in process.

By preventing this, sign in with non-existing user seems to be no problem anymore.

This is my claims factory class:

```
public class MyClaimsFactory : ClaimsIdentityFactory<MyUser, string>
{
    public override async Task<ClaimsIdentity> CreateAsync(UserManager<MyUser, string> manager, MyUser user, string authenticationType)
    {
        if (manager == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("manager");
        if (user == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("user");

        ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(authenticationType, this.UserNameClaimType, this.RoleClaimType);
        claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(this.UserIdClaimType, this.ConvertIdToString(user.Id), "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"));
        claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(this.UserNameClaimType, user.UserName, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"));
        claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("http://schemas.microsoft.com/accesscontrolservice/2010/07/claims/identityprovider", "ASP.NET Identity", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"));

        if (!user.IsGuest)
        {
            if (manager.SupportsUserSecurityStamp)
                claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(this.SecurityStampClaimType, await manager.GetSecurityStampAsync(user.Id).WithCurrentCulture<string>()));

            if (manager.SupportsUserRole)
            {
                IList<string> list = await manager.GetRolesAsync(user.Id).WithCurrentCulture<IList<string>>();
                foreach (string current in list)
                {
                    claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(this.RoleClaimType, current, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"));
                }
            }
            if (manager.SupportsUserClaim)
                claimsIdentity.AddClaims(await manager.GetClaimsAsync(user.Id).WithCurrentCulture<IList<Claim>>());
        }

        return claimsIdentity;
    }
}
```